# Ternary operator with String literals in Android Data Binding Library

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have an `EditText` and I want to set its `inputType` depending on if the `Parameter` is numeric or not:

```
interface Parameter {
    boolean isNumeric();
}
```

I have this:

```
   <EditText
       ...
       android:inputType="@{parameter.isNumeric()? number : text}"/>
```

But there is an error when parsing XML. I have tried by wrapping `number` and `text` values in single and double (escaped) quotation marks.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `number` and `text` values would be considered variables in Java context. You have to make sure to set the appropriate Java value. First you have to import `InputType` in your `<data>` block. Then use the relating integer values.

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="@{parameter.isNumeric() ? InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER : InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT}" />
```